# How to design look up list for 20 sub-sites?

Tags: jquery, lookup-column, dropdown, cascading

Say, I have 20 sub-sites under corporate sales. There are 3 lists that drives the look up columns.

Country (USA, Mexico, Norway, Morocco, etc.)
Regions (SW, NW, S, W, N, MW, etc)
SalesArea (Service; New Sales; SOA)

The Regions and SalesArea constantly gets updated by the legal and sale team. I don't want to maintain these list at sub site level.

Can the site collection host this list so all the sub-site can consume these list for look-up columns?

I know I can create "Site Columns" with lookup type and that way sub-site can consume the Site Column. But I am using spService for cascade dropdown and it needs the list name. Will the spservice jquery cascade dropdown work if the list is not present in the sub-site level?

What would you do? I would truly appreciate your feedback and suggestion.

I thought about creating lists at the site collection and external list at the sub-site level. But then I have to create 60 external list (3 external list per sub-site to consume list from it's parent)

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of lookup I would be tempted to use a hierarchical term set.  You can use a single metadata column instead of the complexity of 3 connected ones.  You can display the full path of the selected term and you can use XSLT to split them into individual values if you need that. Filtering will allow you to filter at any level in the hierarchy and you can give ownership of the term set to the appropriate teams so they can manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Jennifer,

A free solution is available 
http://duallookup.codeplex.com/

Third-party Paid solution
[SharePoint Cross-Site Lookup Column](http://www.sharepointadd-ons.com/sharepoint-cross-site-lookup)

Or maybe you can use InfoPath as shown by Laura Rougers here:
[Cross-Site Lookups in SharePoint 2010 Enterprise](http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=daba3a3b-c338-41d8-bf52-cd897d000cf3&ID=134&Web=dbb90e85-b54c-49f4-8e97-6d8258116ca0)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, spService comes with relationshipWebURL and that's all I needed. This site really helped me.

http://blog.sharepointrx.com/2009/09/11/cascading-drop-downs-in-a-sharepoint-custom-task-form